# ftp to server with uname and pass in comandline

Tags: unix, ftp

From a unix machine I'm trying to FTP to a server but want to log in also in the command line

e.g. ftp 10.2.3.4 username:password

Can't find the general format for doing this? ftp 10.2.3.4 -u username -p password> doesn't appear to work either?

Thanks,

Comment: don't have the man page... why I'm on here

Comment: "don't have the man page"? This is not 1986; every system has documentation. And if for some crazy reason your system is screwed up, there's always your good friend Google.

Comment: what is this a forum for referring people back to their manual? yes there is google, but I'm sure 95% of peoples questions on this forum could be found by spending time on google digging through various websites putting an answer together. That's why they have sites like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of choices here

1. Use a .netrc file.
2. ftp username:password@host

Comment: choice 2 will often result in error `ftp: username:password@host unknown host` or `ftp: username:password@host Name or service not known`

Comment: @thegunner: which ftp daemon have you installed ? I have tried to use .netrc with ftpd, pure-ftpd and vsftpd. It does not work i.e. the prompt for username and password still appears even after specifying them in the .netrc file.

Comment: @user189942 You need to ensure the .netrc is in your home directory and permissions are rw only for yourself. So `chmod 600 ~/.netrc`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this notation : `ftp ftp://username:password@host:port`

---

**Resources :**

- [freebsd.org - man ftp](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ftp)